# Can't delete row in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm beginner in Realm programming.I wrote code and i can insert some values in my Realm Database.Now i want to check if item is not same in Realm table. First time,I selected item by key and if exist-I deleted it, and then i inserted new item.
This is my code

```
private void insertIntoDatabase()
{
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<VinScannerHistoryModel> rows =
                    realm.where(VinScannerHistoryModel.class)
                            .equalTo("userName",vinScannerModel.getName())
                            .equalTo("vinNumber",vinNumber.getText().toString())
                            .findAll();
            if(rows!=null)
            {
                rows.clear();
                realm.commitTransaction();

            }
        }
    });


        ImagesObject imagesObject = mRealm.createObject(ImagesObject.class);
        VinScannerHistoryModel vinScannerHistoryModel = mRealm.createObject(VinScannerHistoryModel.class);
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setVinNumber(vinNumber.getText().toString());
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setStatus(status);
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setModel(model);

        vinScannerHistoryModel.setYear(year);

        vinScannerHistoryModel.setVin(vin);
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setTerminal_out_date(terminal_out_date);
        if(Global.imagePath!=null && Global.imagePath.size()>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Global.imagePath.size(); i++) {
                imagesObject.setImageName(Global.imagePath.get(i));
                vinScannerHistoryModel.getImagesObjects().add(imagesObject);

            }

        }
        if(checkBox.isChecked())
            vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("1");
        else
            vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("0");
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setPolygon(polygonAdapter.getItem(spinnerPosition).getId()+"");
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setUserName(vinScannerModel.getName());
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

When I run my app,I hava crash

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().
```

I don't know what is a wrong and how i can solve this problem?
P.S
As I said ,I'm beginner Realm programming and in your options,is it a correct way to remove duplicate items in my DB
thanks

Comment: `mRealm.beginTransaction();` and `mRealm.executeTransaction()` both start a new transaction, except `executeTransaction()` also handles exceptions by cancelling the transaction instead of just letting it linger around.

Comment: As for "removing duplications"? Use a `@PrimaryKey` so that you don't have "duplications"

Answer (score 0):

Text of exception is quite clear, isn't it? You can not  start transaction inside transaction.

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();

RealmResults<VinScannerHistoryModel> rows =
        realm.where(VinScannerHistoryModel.class)
                .equalTo("userName", vinScannerModel.getName())
                .equalTo("vinNumber", vinNumber.getText().toString())
                .findAll();
if (rows != null) {
    rows.clear();
}
....
....
```

Comment: How i can remove item and then add new item?

Comment: Remove item first, then add new item.

Comment: I try to remove first time and then add new item,but i have crash.can you show me code without crash?

Comment: Show stack trace of exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct answer.I solved my self

```
RealmResults<VinScannerHistoryModel> results
            = mRealm.where(VinScannerHistoryModel.class)
            .equalTo("userName",vinScannerModel.getName())
            .equalTo("vinNumber",vinNumber.getText().toString())
            .findAll();

    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    if(results!=null)
        results.clear();
```